# Fatal exception asynctask #2 when trying to Post Data to HTTP

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, postdata

Been trying to post data to HTTP server.  Essentially I created a input text field and a button so when I type in data, button will allow me to post it.  However, every time I enter a number and press the button, the program crashes.  Below is the error.

```
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781): Process: org.example.androidsdk.demo, PID: 1781
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=volta.sdsu.edu/~biocom/PHP/PHPService/index.php
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at org.example.androidsdk.demo.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.postData(MainActivity.java:96)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at org.example.androidsdk.demo.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at org.example.androidsdk.demo.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-18 19:11:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     ... 4 more
```

my code in main activity is:

```
package org.example.androidsdk.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText value;
    private Button btn;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){
        // out of range
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());  
        }
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{
         @Override
         protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         postData(params[0]);
         return null;
         }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }


    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // specify the URL you want to post to
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("volta.sdsu.edu/~biocom/PHP/PHPService/index.php");
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PatientId", "1"));
//          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DataType", "Pulse"));
//          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DataValue", "70.99"));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // process exception
            } catch (IOException e) {
                }
        }
    }


    public void gotoActivity(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void gotoHeart(View v){

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, HeartRateActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent2);

    }

    public void gotoTemperature(View v){
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, TemperatureActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent3);
    }

    public void gotoText(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Emergency!");
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(intent);
    }



}
```

The last 3 buttons that opens another page works smoothly.  Just the first part of text field and submit that's giving me trouble when I try to call the posting of the HTTP.  Any help is appreciated.  Oh and I did enable android.permission.INTERNET in the manifest.

Comment: Try adding http:// to your url, I don't think its parsing right

Comment: this might not be the best place to ask it but now I'm getting a response from the server of the data I posted but how do I get that data to also display on my app?